# Can Sketch display a list of fonts and weights in use by the current document?

Tags: sketch-app

I have Sketch v51.3.

Can Sketch display a list of the fonts and respective weights in use by the current document?

I know when I open a Sketch document, it will prompt me to resolve missing fonts.  I have also noticed when I create a text path, the font selector drop down appears to offer the fonts already used by other paths in the document at the top of the total available font list.

However, I cannot find a display, toolbox, window, preference, info box, etc. which simply lists all the fonts, with respective weights, in use.  Must I click on every path and manually note the font and weight?

I want the information which is more or less exactly the "missing fonts" dialog.

This seems obvious, I must be overlooking something but Sketch help reveals nothing, I've searched all the menus, and the Sketch document on "text". Must I click on every path and manually note the font and weight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sketch plugin [Fontily](https://sketchapphub.com/resource/fontily/) can do exactly what you asked for!

[image: Fontily Interface]

After you installed the plugin, Fontily will show you all the fonts and weights used in the file, and it'll highlight the missing ones. You can even replace them if you want.